# Build a 1toM queryset that sorts for foreignkey

Tags: django, orm, django-templates, django-queryset

How to build a query to get a output of all tasks in a project with a certain author? In my Template i want to iterate over all Projects and show all tasks below the parent Project.

```
{% for p in projects %}
add project html
  {% for t in projects.tasks %}
    add task html
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Models:**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projectname_text = models.CharField('Projectname', unique=True, max_length=200)

class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    task_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='author')
```

I hope someone is able help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you modify the `project` field on your `Task` model as follows:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                related_name='tasks')
    # ...
```

This will let you access all the tasks for a particular project through `project.tasks.all()`.

You also need to modify your template slightly, because you're currently referring to `projects` where you should refer to `p`, and you need to loop over `p.tasks.all` not just `p.tasks`.

```
{% for p in projects %}
add project html
  {% for t in p.tasks.all %}
    add task html
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You'll need to ensure that `projects` is in the context passed to your template by your view.

Comment: Thanks, the "p.tasks.all" inside the template got me there :)